# Blender 2.82 animation nodes toolbar is missing

Tags: animation-nodes

Animation nodes toolbar is missing.

Latest AN for blender 2.8x installed and works.

Only the toolbar not shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the new version (2.17) of Animation Nodes the *Node Tree Options* are present in the **Sidebar** (Right panel). Use <kbd>N</kbd> to reveal the panel.
[image]